# Weather App using react always return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openweathermap

I am trying to create a WeatherApp using React and OpenWeathermap API as beginner project. After fetching the data from the API, I am not able to return any component as it always returns null from the conditional statement.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from "react";


 export default function App(){

 const API_KEY = somekey; 

 const [lat, setLat] = useState([]);
 const [long, setLong] = useState([]);
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
       console.log(position.coords.latitude);
       setLat([position.coords.latitude]); //sets latitude
       setLong([position.coords.longitude]); //sets longitude
     });
     await fetch(
       `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&exclude=hourly,minutely&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`
     )
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then((result) => {
         setData([result]);
         console.log(data);
       });
   };
   fetchData();
 }, [lat, long]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {(typeof data.main !== 'undefined') ? (
        <h1>{data.name}</h1>  //doesnt execute
      ) :null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The project is based on this example:https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-react-by-building-a-weather-app/

Comment: what does console.log(result) output ?

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous ... so, you `fetch` before `setLat` etc is called

Comment: There's no point using `async/await` if you're also going to use `then`. Your `useEffect` is a little weird too. It will only call if `lat` or `lng` have changed but in order to change them you have to use that `useEffect` which you can't do because those dependencies haven't changed.

Comment: @ElheniMokhles it outputs null object at the beginning and later it outputs the weather data object.

Comment: @Andy so should I fetch the data outside the `useEffect`?

Comment: Ideally you'd want one `useEffect` to get the lat/lng using an empty dependency array `[]` which is called once when the component is initially rendered, and the one you're currently using to get the weather data when those states change. I'd also advise that you use an object `{ lat, lng }` for your coords so you don't have too many states.

Comment: @Andy so I should declare two `useEffect` functions then? One for the initial rendering of lat/long and then later to fetch data from API and to use `setLat` and `setLong` ?

Comment: Initially that's how I would do it, yes @Ann. But you could also look [into using established hooks](https://react-hooks.org/docs/useGeolocation), for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous you call `fetch` before `setLat` etc is called

Note: my knowledge of `reactjs` is limited, so perhaps you can't do the following in `useEffect` - apologies in advance if that's the case

In `fetchData` you would get the data from *openweathermap* in the callback in `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` - like so

```
const fetchData = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        setLat([position.coords.latitude]); //sets latitude
        setLong([position.coords.longitude]); //sets longitude
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&exclude=hourly,minutely&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            setData([result]);
        });
    });
};
```

Note, not using any `async` since there's no use of `await`

If you want to use async await, you could "promisify" `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` like so

```
const getCurrentPosition = options => new Promise((resolve, reject) => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options));
```

then you can use it like so

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const position = await getCurrentPosition(); // the promisified function above
    setLat([position.coords.latitude]); //sets latitude
    setLong([position.coords.longitude]); //sets longitude

    const res = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&exclude=hourly,minutely&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`);
    const result = await res.json();
    
    setData([result]);
};
```

Note also, that in both cases, the code uses `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude` in the call to *openweathermap* rather than `lat` and `long` - because of my lack of knowledge regarding reactjs, I don't know if `setLat` for instance, changes `lat` "synchronously" or not (again, my reactjs knowledge is very limited)

Comment: after "promisifying" the getpostion function, it worked thanks!